# Exception TypeError using Matplotlib imshow animate using ArtistAnimation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, typeerror

I am trying to use the example for [imshow animate using ArtistAnimation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image2.html) in order to animate a sequence of 2D arrays that I obtain from a file. In order to do it I need to use the ArtistAnimation inside of a function, but this simple change gives me a TypeError that I don't understand. The modification that I did is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation




def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)
# ims is a list of lists, each row is a list of artists to draw in the
# current frame; here we are just animating one artist, the image, in
# each frame
def animate(x,y):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ims = []
    for i in range(60):
        x += np.pi / 15.
        y += np.pi / 20.
        im = plt.imshow(f(x, y), animated=True)
        ims.append([im])


    ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)

    # ani.save('dynamic_images.mp4')

    plt.show()
```

And the TypeError message I receive is:

```
In [23]: animate(x,y)
Exception TypeError: TypeError("'instancemethod' object is not connected",) in <bound method TimerQT.__del__ of <matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5.TimerQT object at 0x7f964ea06150>> ignored
```

Comment: The code you show here makes little to no sense. What are the reasons for changing the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [animation documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#animation) says: "it is critical to keep a reference to the instance object".
Also, you need to call `plt.show()` at the very end.
While this is not a problem when being run as a script, in a jupyter notebook you'd need to change the code to something like

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)

x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 120)
y = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100).reshape(-1, 1)

def animate(x,y):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ims = []
    for i in range(60):
        x += np.pi / 15.
        y += np.pi / 20.
        im = plt.imshow(f(x, y), animated=True)
        ims.append([im])

    ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, blit=True,
                                repeat_delay=1000)

    return ani
```

and then call it like

```
ani = animate(x,y)
plt.show()
```

to keep the reference to the animation.